# How should I write multiple loops for a single operation in python

Tags: python, loops, parsing

I'm new to learning python and I really need to get this job done, and I really dont know how to look for an answer in what it seems to be a big giant ocean of information.

I'm working with a PDB parser and I have the following code:

```
#Calling the module
from Bio.PDB.PDBParser import PDBParser

#Defining some variables
parser = PDBParser(PERMISSIVE=1)
structure_id= "3caq"
filename = "3caq.pdb"

#This is the actual task to be done
structure = parser.get_structure(structure_id, filename)

#What I'm interested in doing
compound = structure.header['compound']
print structure_id + " |", compound
```

with this result:

> 3caq | {'1': {'synonym': 'delta(4)-3-ketosteroid 5-beta-reductase, aldo-keto reductase family 1 member d1 ', 'chain': 'a, b', 'misc': '', 'molecule': '3-oxo-5-beta-steroid 4-dehydrogenase', 'ec_number': '1.3.1.3','ec': '1.3.1.3', 'engineered': 'yes'}}

The thing is that I'm not working with just a single file (defined under "filename") but I have hundreds of files from where I need to extract the "header", and only retain the "compound" variable of said header.

I know I have to write loops for that to be done and I tried the following:

```
#Defining lists
nicknames = { "3caq", "2zb7" }
structures = { "3caq.pdb", "2bz7.pdb" }

structure_id = []
for structure in structures:
       structure_id.append(nickname)
filename = []
for structure in structures:
       filename.append(structure)
```

then I feed the parser but I get an error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tomas/Escritorio/d.py", line 16, in <module>
   header = parser.get_structure(structure_id, filename)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Bio/PDB/PDBParser.py"
  , line 82, in get_structure
   self._parse(handle.readlines())
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'readlines'
```

I'm pretty sure that the loop is not correctly written.

So, I'll be really thankful if I can get some help with how to correctly write that loop, either with a resource I can check, or with the right commands.

Best regards.

Comment: _"I get an error"_ - Can you please post the full error you're getting?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot about it

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tomas/Escritorio/d.py", line 16, in <module>
    header = parser.get_structure(structure_id, filename)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Bio/PDB/PDBParser.py", line 82, in get_structure
    self._parse(handle.readlines())
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'readlines'

Comment: Post it in your question please.

Comment: Does the first block of code work?

Comment: yes, the first block of code works. I get the information from the pdb file header one at a time. I'll add it in the question.

Comment: Sounds like you are passing a list when it expects a file-like object.  You should look in ```PDBParser.py``` and find the ```_parser``` method to see if it has a docstring that might give you a hint.  Or [catch the exception](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) and print some relevant data in the except suite.

Comment: Is the nickname/structure_id always the same as the filename prefix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting an error because you're passing a list (`["3caq.pdb"]`) when `get_structure()` expects a string (`"3caq.pdb"`).

Here is how you can support multiple files:

```
from Bio.PDB.PDBParser import PDBParser

files = {"3caq.pdb", "2bz7.pdb"}

for filename in files:
    # Defining some variables
    parser = PDBParser(PERMISSIVE=1)

    # Drop ".pdb" from filename to get structure_id
    structure_id = filename.split('.')[0]

    # This is the actual task to be done
    structure = parser.get_structure(structure_id, filename)

    # What I'm interested in doing
    compound = structure.header['compound']

    print("{} | {}".format(structure_id, compound))
```

To make your code even better, I would write it as a separate function:

```
from Bio.PDB.PDBParser import PDBParser

def get_compound_header(filename):
    # Defining some variables
    parser = PDBParser(PERMISSIVE=1)

    # Drop ".pdb" from filename to get structure_id
    structure_id = filename.split('.')[0]

    # This is the actual task to be done
    structure = parser.get_structure(structure_id, filename)

    # What I'm interested in doing
    compound = structure.header['compound']

    return "{} | {}".format(structure_id, compound)


# Main function
if __name__ == "__main__":

    files = {"3caq.pdb", "2bz7.pdb"}

    for filename in files:
        print(get_compound_header(filename))
```

Answer (score 0):

Clear understanding would help you sort this out.

You need to iterate through many structures so good choice with the for loop. I would suggest you use a list instead of set to store the structures and filenames.

```
filenames = ["3caq", "2zb7" ]
structures = ["3caq.pdb", "2bz7.pdb"]
```

Now you can iterate by the length of the structures.

```
for each in range(len(structures)):
    structure = parser.get_structure(structures[each], filenames[each])

    compound = structure.header['compound']
    print structure_id + " |", compound
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Oh, yeah! thanks :) I will edit it
Anything with index would help here.

Comment: You could use [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to pair the nicknames with the filenames and dispense with the indices.

Comment: It also worked! thank you very much. I had to edit the last string which endend up like: print filenames[each] + " |", compound